# Serving Geo-spatial data in MongoDB through GeoServer

Tags: java, mongodb, geojson, geoserver

I have Geo-spatial data stored in a MongoDB data store which I would like to serve up through GeoServer so that the data can be consumed though WFS, WMS, etc.  I was able to install GeoServer and drop in the gt-mongodb plugin that's packaged with GeoTools and also install the MongoDb driver for Java.  After doing this I was able to Mongo as a an option in when adding a data store.  However, after creating a new MongoDB store I am unable to create a new vector layer; I continue to get the following error : "could not create vector layer: null".

Here is what I'm doing :

- under the data section, I click "layers"
- "add new resource"
- select the mongodb store I created from the dropdown
- "create new feature types"
- "add new attribute" and add several fields from my data
- enter a "type name" and click save.

I'm sort of new the GeoServer and despite searching in every way I can think of, was unable to find documentation pertaining to MongoDB plugin for GeoServer.  I've been told that the only other option I might have it to write my own MongoDB extension for GeoServer.  Before I go down that path, I was hoping to find some documentation on this or examples how someone might have gotten it to work.  I appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Did you make sure that you downloaded the correct version of the plugin to match your GeoServer version? Failing that look in the log file to see what it says.

Comment: @iant, I'm using gt-mongodb-9.4.jar with GeoServer 2.5.2.  As far as I can tell, this should be okay.  Do you see any issue with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone runs into the same issue as me, here is a solution.

After digging through the plugin code, I realized that the plugin expects a couple stored javascript functions to exist on mongo.  I found the javascript files and instructions on installing them inside the Jar file.  However, even after installing the javacript functions it would not work (I'm guessing because of an incompatibility between my mongodb version and the way the driver calls the function, but this is mostly a guess.  I didn't look too deeply into what the root issue is it because I found a working solution, but I think this should work for mongodb versions before 2.4, or you'd have to alter the driver.)

While I was considering modifying the driver to work in this situation, I found out that BoundlessGeo publishes a driver that's newer and works faster and is easier to use.

Here is the github repo : https://github.com/boundlessgeo/geoserver-exts for geoserver-exts.  The instruction are on the readme, but basically you "git clone" and then do a "mvn install" and it build the drivers for you (the driver jar should look something like : gt-mongo-15-SNAPSHOT.jar).

The instruction for installation can be found here : https://github.com/boundlessgeo/suite/blob/master/docs/usermanual/source/dataadmin/mongodb/store.rst#id19.